# cp command fails when run in a script called by Hudson

Tags: bash, ssh, hudson, embedded-linux, scp

This one is a puzzler.  If I run a command from the command line to copy a file remotely it works perfectly.  If I run that same command inside a script on the server (that hosts Hudson), it runs perfectly as well, same for running the job as hudson from the command line.  However, if I run that exact command as a function inside a bash script from a Hudson job, it fails with:

```
cp: cannot stat '/opt/flash_board.tar.gz': No such file or directory
```

The variable is defined as:

```
original_tarball=flash_board.tar.gz
```

and is in scope (variable expansion works correctly in the script).

The original command is:

```
ssh -n -o stricthostkeychecking=no root@$IP_ADDRESS ssh -n -o stricthostkeychecking=no 169.254.0.2 cp /opt/$original_tarball /opt/$original_tarball.bak
```

I've also tried it as:

```
ssh -n -p 1601 -o stricthostkeychecking=no root@$IP_ADDRESS cp /opt/$original_tarball /opt/$original_tarball.bak
```

which points to the correct port, but fails in exactly the same way.

For reference all the variables have been checked to be valid.  I originally thought this was a substitution error, but that doesn't seem to be the case, so then I tried running it with Hudson credentials as:

```
sudo -u hudson ssh -n -o stricthostkeychecking=no root@$IP_ADDRESS ssh -n -o stricthostkeychecking=no 169.254.0.2 cp /opt/$original_tarball /opt/$original_tarball.bak
```

I get the exact same results (it works).  So it's only when this command is run from a Hudson job that it fails.

Here's the sequence of events:

- Hudson job sets parameters & calls a shell script.
- A function inside the script tries to copy the files remotely from an embedded Montevista (Linux) board across an SPI bus to a second embedded Arago (Linux) board
- Both boards are physically on the same mother board, but there's no way to directly access the Arago board except through a serial console session (which isn't feasible, this is an automation job that runs across the network).

I've tried this using ssh with -p 1601 (the correct port to the Arago side).

Can I use scp to copy a remote file to the same location as the remote file with a different file extension?

Something like:

```
scp -o stricthostkeychecking=no root@$IP_ADDRESS /opt/$original_tarball /opt/$original_tarball.bak
```

I had a couple of the devs take a look at this and they were stumped as well.  Anyone got any ideas (A) why this fails & (B) how to work around it.  I'm pretty sure I can write a script to run locally on the remote machine, but that doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

Oh, and if I run the exact same command on the Montevista board (which means I don't have to go across the SPI bus (169.254.0.2), it works perfectly from the Hudson job.

Comment: Deployment diagram pls? I'm confused by the double ssh in your fifth code block. I'd up the -vv on ssh and print as much environment information (PATH, `which cp` etc) as possible from a test script to find differences.

Comment: @themel.  I'm too new to be allowed to upload images.  The double ssh allows me to go from the hudson server to the Montevista board, which is in communication with the Arago board across an SPI link, so the second ssh to 169.254.0.2 is to make that jump.  I have no way to directly access the Arago board, I either have to go through port 1601 or do the double ssh to get there (both of which work just fine with any number of other bash commands, although I have to be careful as there are different versions of busybox on both boards).

Comment: @UsmanSaleem This may be demonstrating my lack of Linux knowledge, but if I'm logged on as root (which I am), don't I have superuser credentials?  If I try to do "sudo" anything on either board, it tells me:  -sh: sudo: not found.  That's not to say it couldn't still be a permissions issue, but since it works flawlessly on the Montevista board, but not the Arago board it would seem like this isn't the problem, but I'll still look into it, there are many differences between the two that aren't well documented.  Thanks for the idea, and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Try to save the file in /tmp instead of /opt and change your script accordingly. As David W. pointed out in his answer, the hudson user probably doesn't has rights on /opt and/or the actual file.

Comment: If its a permissions problem, you should get a permission denied error, not a file not found. Even if its the lack of +x on a parent directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this turned out to be something completely unrelated to the question.  I broke the problem down into little pieces with a test Hudson script, adding more and more complexity from the original script till it failed as before.

It turned out to be pilot error, I'd written an `if` statement to differentiate between the two boards (Arago & Montevista) and then abstracted out the variables passed to the `if` statement to the point where it was ambiguous which board was being passed in, so the `if` logic always grabbed the first match (as it should) and the flash script I was trying to copy on the Arago board didn't exist on the Montevista board (well, it has a different name) so the error returned was absolutely correct.

Sorry for the spin up and thanks for all the effort to help.

Answer (score 0):

> cp: cannot stat '/opt/flash_board.tar.gz': No such file or directory

This is saying that Hudson cannot see the file. I would do a `ls -la /opt` in that shell script of yours. This will show you the permissions on the `/opt` directory, and whether your script can list that file.

While you're at it, do a `du -f` on the Hudson machine too and see if that `/opt` directory is a remote mount or something that could be problematic.

You've already said that you logged in as the user that runs the Hudson task and execute it from the workspace directory.

Right now, I suspect that the directory permission is an issue.

Comment: Your recommendation was the root of the solution, the test script that I wrote did as you suggested, then I added copying with explicit names, which worked perfectly.  Then I added variable names, which continued to work, so then I added the if statements to differentiate between the boards, and voila, it started failing.  I set -xv on the entire script and realized that the if statement was always choosing the first presented option.  This was difficult to discern because the 2 if statements are virtually identical, but the differences finally jumped out at me.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way that goes wrong is that somehow it is being run on the wrong machine, possibly due to either a line length limit, or to weird quoting issues.

I'd try changing the command to `… uname -a` or `… hostname -f` to see if you get the right machine. Or, alternatively, `… cp /proc/cpuinfo /tmp/this-machine` and then see which machine gets the file.

**edit:** I see now that OP has answered his own question. I guess I'll leave this here in case it helps any future visitors with similar issues. I guess I should add "or not running the command you thing you're running" to the reasons why it could happen.